# Writing a value to local DB

Tags: c#, database, datatable

I have a database and dataset to interact with it,

```
SampleDatabaseDataSet database = new SampleDatabaseDataSet();
SampleDatabaseDataSet.Table1Row table1 = database.Table1.NewTable1Row();
table1.call_id = 55;
database.Table1.Rows.Add(table1);
```

The error I'm getting is in **table1.call_id**

`'table1.call_id' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException'  int {System.InvalidCastException}`

Comment: usually we use long for the id field

Comment: Double check the data type for your `call_id` column. If it is not an `int` you will have to cast 55 to a different type.

Comment: I'm positive it's an int. if there was a way i could show you. Can you link images?

Comment: Put your break point on the line and hover mouse above `call_id`